# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 6567

Tags: angularjs, asmx

I am using angular js and web service(asmx) coding to connect to database.
I have written the following code in controler:

```
 var parameter = { "CartID": CartID, "Quantity": Quantity, "CostCode": costcode, "DebitTo": debitto, "ItemPriceID": ItemPriceid, "TotalPrice": TotalPrice, "LocationCode": location };
                        alert(JSON.stringify(parameter));
                        $http({
                            method: 'post',
                            data: parameter,
                            url: 'wfrmOrderPlacement.asmx/AddItemsToCart',
                        }).then(function (response) {  
//Some methods here.........  
}
```

It worked fine ..

But the same way i have use another http call for accessing another method in asmx like below:

```
 var parameter = { "SelectedLocationcode": location };
                alert(JSON.stringify(parameter));
                $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    data:parameter,
                    url: 'wfrmOrderPlacement.asmx/GetItemDetails',                        
                }).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.items = response.data;
});
```

but this is giving the mentioned error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 6567

It is working fine when i remove my parameters that i am passing to web method

Comment: Hi, Try removing the comma(,) after url

Comment: @M3ghana i have tried removing comma, Its of no use; still the same problem....

Comment: Can you paste the line previous to the var parameter?

Comment: var location = $scope.SelectedLocationcode;

and i am calling the entire method in a function
 $scope.getitemdetails = function () {
}

Comment: This is likely an error with your backend logic that is serving data

Comment: i think there is no prob with the back end logic bcoz when i am running it it is giving me desired output  provided the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I guess the parameter which you are passing is having some code with braces{}...Can you replace data:parameter with data:"dummy parameterstring"

We can check if it is issue with data passed

Comment: even if i pass my parameter like 
 var parameter = { "SelectedLocationcode": "39" };
and 
                        method: 'post',
                        data:parameter,
                        url: 'wfrmOrderPlacement.asmx/GetItemDetails'   
It is giving me the same error